# Who is Stan Lee talking to in his cameo in "Guardians of the Galaxy"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, stan-lee

The  person he is talking to looks quite familiar, I think she appears in other MCU contexts as well.

[image: Rocket's view looking at Stan Lee as a Xandarian talking to a younger woman]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### No one in particular<sup>1</sup>

The actress that plays the character is [Nicole Alexandra Shipley](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm4397494/) and here is the [MCU wiki page for her](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Nicole_Alexandra_Shipley). She only appears in *Guardians of the Galaxy* and only in Stan Lee's cameo where she is credited as "Pretty Xandarian". So, as of yet, she's a nobody in the MCU.

[image: Screenshot of the credits with Nicole's role as Pretty Xandarian highlighted]

---

<sub>*1. Disclaimer: so **far** she is no one in particular but that **could** change even if I doubt it.*</sub>

Comment: FWIW, and I accidentally crossed through it, but Stan Lee is credited above as Xandarian Ladies' Man. So the two, having appeared at the same time, are credited next to each other.

Comment: Given they didn't even bother giving her a *name*, it'd be pretty surprising if she ended up being someone important.  And for basically nothing more than an excuse for a Stan Lee cameo, if she did appear again, almost nobody would even remember her.  You'd get a very few "Hey, it's that random lady Stan Lee was hitting on that one time!"  But mostly it'd be a lot of "Who the heck is she supposed to be?"

Comment: @DarrelHoffman now that Stan can't do any more cameos it might be fun to throw in cameos of random peeps like her that appeared in the cameos he's done to date instead, that'd make for a dang hard easter egg to spot, even if you just pick one of them at random & use that one for all the sans-Stan cameo spots.

Comment: Having said that ^ if I was Stan I'd have contractually obliged them to use CGI to digitally insert cameo appearances after I was dead, anyone know if that might happen?

Comment: @Pelinore Unlikely, he didn't appear in FFH, WandaVision or F&TWS (so far). I doubt they'll do it.

Comment: Is there likely to be a connection between the similarity over the letters x-a-n-d of her middle name, Alexandra, to the character being a Xandarian?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Xandar has been around in the comics for decades. It would be very odd to pick an actress for a 10 second cameo of Stan Lee over some random letters in her middle name.

Comment: Fair enough, it does look like there are quite a few actors in SF whose names have a less-then-cryptic connection to the names of the characters they play. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Maybe you're confusing her with Marisa Tomei as Aunt May. Not that much of a resemblance though.

Comment: Hi there, MCU producer from the future! When you get to introduce this fine lady as a main character in a future movie, please call her `Xandra Es-Efef` or something similar - we'll know.